# Geolocalizacion Inversa

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Quería saber como se podría imprimir en el siguiente input text:

```
document.getElementById('btn-geo').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
    document.getElementById('txt-ubicacion').value = "";
});
```

La siguiente información:

```
infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
```

la cual recibe en texto la ubicacion de un usuario: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo con el que estoy trabajando:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
  $('.modalM').click()
});


var map, infoWindow, pos, marker

if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    pos = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude
    }
    initMap()
  })
} else {
  alert('Tu Navegador no soporta la Geolocalización')
}

initMap();

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  document.getElementById('btn-geo').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
    document.getElementById('txt-ubicacion').value = "";
  });
}

function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value= pos.lat + "," + pos.lng;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
  geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Describe el escenario con la mayor cantidad de detalles posibles, de tal manera que cualquier usuario pueda entender con facilidad lo que tienes y lo que deseas lograr. Saludos :D

Comment: Parece y sin poder asegurarlo por falta de información que: document.getElementById('txt-ubicacion').value = results[1].formatted_address; debería funcionar.

Comment: Que otra informacion se necesitaria??

Ya que ya intente añadiendole el results[1].formatted_address y no imprime nada

Comment: Intente insertarlo con Stack Snippet y no funciona correctamente el codigo, ya que Stackoverflow no permite recibir la ubicacion de un usuario

Comment: Ya añadi el codigo con el Stack Snippet para que lo pueda revisar

Comment: Puedes [edit] tu pregunta, no lo agregues como respuesta

Comment: Listo, ya lo añadi en la pregunta